# What happens when a non-U.S. citizen who's been making money from the U.S. moves to the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, non-resident

So I've been making money from the US over the Internet, money that has been wiring from affiliate companies, PayPal, and Google to my home country. I never reported any taxes because of my non-US activities. Now I want to come and live in the US for a while, very likely, with all the income being deposited in a local bank account that I would open somewhere in California.

My question is, what should I expect with this whole new situation? What am I supposed to do exactly financial-wise?

I suppose I need to report and pay taxes as I'm conducting business on the American soil, right? If so, is there any good tutorial to start with, for a foreigner?

I currently have no idea what I should do with the income coming into my US bank account every month (approx. 10g/m). I tried to search online for advice but only to find them primarily for US citizens. As I'm a foreigner in US I suppose things are different. So I'm here for help. Any tips would be appreciated.

**Update:** My primary sources of income are as follows.

1. Developing software and selling them to U.S. customers via Internet (download & membership subscription via PayPal).
2. Brokering / introducing US customers to U.S. companies for sales commissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not for US citizens - its for [US residents](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Determining-Alien-Tax-Status). If the US considers you as a tax resident - you'll be treated the same as a US citizen, regardless of your immigration status.

The question is very unclear, since it is not mentioned whether your US sourced income "from the Internet" is sales in the US, sales on-line, services you provide, investments, or what else. All these are treated differently. For some kinds of US-sourced income you should have paid taxes in the US already, regardless of where you physically reside. For others - not.

In any case, if you become [US tax resident](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Determining-Alien-Tax-Status), you'll be taxed on your *worldwide* income, not only the $10K deposited in the US bank account. **ALL** of your income, everywhere in the world, must be declared to the US government and will be taxed.

You should seek professional advice, *before* you move to the US, in order to understand your responsibilities, liabilities and rights. I suggest looking for a EA/CPA licensed in California and experienced with taxation of foreigners (look for someone in the SF or LA metropolitan areas).

Keep in mind that there may be a tax treaty between the US and your home country that may affect your Federal (but not California) taxes.

Comment: +1 - Thanks for jumping in. And the combo of great detailed response including linked references and 'seek a pro' pretty much nails it. Will wait till tomorrow and then issue bounty.

Comment: My 2 sources of income: 1. Developing software and selling them to US customers via Internet. 2. Brokering / introducing US customers to US companies for sales commissions.

Comment: You're welcome. It's time to get some good answers to these unanswered questions. Glad to start with yours.

Comment: @kavoir.com both are likely to be taxable when you're doing it while on the US soil (regardless of your tax status), and #2 may even be taxable if you're out of the country (though I'm not sure about it).

Comment: @littleadv I don't have a green card, so basically if I pass the [substantial presence test](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Substantial-Presence-Test), I will report and pay taxes just as how the native U.S. citizens are doing. Otherwise if I'm a non-resident alien, I'll just go with the [instructions here](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Taxation-of-Nonresident-Aliens). Correct?

Comment: @yes, but pay attention: even as non-resident you pay taxes on anything earned while on the American soil. Non-earned income is treated differently.